# How to detect if the viewed page is a subcategory

Tags: prestashop

I'm actually working on a webcommerce project with Prestashop 1.4.9 and I would like to detect the current viewed page and to find if that page is a subcategory or not (in category.tpl file for example).

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it !
With `$category->level_depth` we can determine if the current page is a category or a subcategory.
In my case i had to use :

```
{if $category->level_depth == 2}
{/if}
```

Answer (score 2):

Right.In ps_category table you have column level_depth for each category.If level_depth ==2, this is category, if level_depth ==3 is subcategory.See more details there.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can check it by id_parent . If a category is a sub category of another one, then the parent category id is placed in id_parent column, else it will be 0 . so you can check it like

```
{if $category->id_parent != 0}
 ......
 ......
{/if}
```

The level depth will be also fine, but it is used for the depth in the category tree, like at which depth it will be. Level depth 2 means, that the category has parent which have no parent category, like the category has a father but no grandfather :) . And level 3 means the category has a father, and also the category has a grand father ;) .

I think best will be to use id_parent.

Thank you